# ¿Como hago que funcione para el numero 5?

Tags: java, hilos

El ejercicio es el siguiente  Dado un entero **n** divisible por **5**, calcula la suma de todos los enteros desde **1** hasta **n**, ambos incluidos. Divide el trabajo en, al menos, 5 hilos.

Funciona perfectamente para todos lo numero menos para el 5.

```
public class Hilo extends Thread {

    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int suma = 0;
    private static int numHilos = 0;

    public Hilo(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public Hilo() {
    }

    public int getSuma() {
        return suma;
    }

    public void setSuma(int suma) {
        this.suma = suma;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
            suma += i;
        }
    }
}
```

Class Número:

```
public class Numero {

    private static int numero;

    public static int getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public static void setNumero(int numero) {
        Numero.numero = numero;
    }

    public static List partes(int numero) {
        List<Integer> limites = new ArrayList<>();
        if (numero % 5 == 0) {
            limites.add(1);
            int c = numero / 5;
            limites.add(c);
            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                int a;
                if (c == 1) {
                    a = i;
                } else {
                    a = c * i + 1;
                }
                limites.add(a);
                int b = c * (i + 1);
                limites.add(b);
            }
        }
        return limites;
    }

}
```

El main:

```
@SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduce el numero divisible por 5: ");
        Numero.setNumero(Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine()));
        List partes = Numero.partes(Numero.getNumero());
        Hilo sum1 = new Hilo((int) partes.get(0), (int) partes.get(1));
        Hilo sum2 = new Hilo((int) partes.get(2), (int) partes.get(3));
        Hilo sum3 = new Hilo((int) partes.get(4), (int) partes.get(5));
        Hilo sum4 = new Hilo((int) partes.get(6), (int) partes.get(7));
        Hilo sum5 = new Hilo((int) partes.get(8), (int) partes.get(9));
        sum1.start();
        sum2.start();
        sum3.start();
        sum4.start();
        sum5.start();
        sum1.join();
        sum2.join();
        sum3.join();
        sum4.join();
        sum5.join();
        int suma = sum1.getSuma() + sum2.getSuma() + sum3.getSuma() + sum4.getSuma() + sum5.getSuma();
        System.out.println("La suma de todos los enteros desde 1 al " + Numero.getNumero() + " es: " + suma);
    }

}
```

Comment: Porque repetiste tu pregunta?

Comment: el  `new Hilo((int) partes.get(0), (int) partes.get(1));` deberia estar dentro de un for y seria el modulo de `partes / 5`

Comment: no entiendo a donde quieres ir a parar con eso que tiene que ver el main con el run del hilo mi problema esta en el run para el numero 5